# Unable to use WebClient in xamarin.Forms portable project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, webclient

I am pretty new in xamarin.form Portable project, I can use httpClient but unable to use WebClient while I have the System.IO namespaces added into the file. My application is targetting application version 4.5 which is by default, I have never changed any targeted version.

Anyone can please let me know how can I use WebClient in xamarin.forms Portable project?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use the WebClient in a PCL, because it is not compatible.

You can read an introduction to PCLs [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/introduction_to_portable_class_libraries/) in the Xamarin documentation. In short it describes that with a PCL you define a certain profile (expressed in 3 numbers like 111 or 259) and depending on that profile you only have the subset of .NET libraries available which are available on *all* targeted platforms.

The `WebClient` is one that isn't very broadly supported. To my knowledge there isn't very much documentation available on what is or isn't supported with the different profiles.

Of course I don't know what you are trying to do exactly, but there are some alternatives.

- Use the `HttpClient` like you've said yourself
- Use [Refit](https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit) to generate a type-safe REST API client for you
- Or find even [other ways](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/#Consuming_REST_Services) to do it

Comment: you are right, but in xamarin development forum they frequenty used WebClient, without writing any word about profiles, so it seems misguide for beginners, at least they must have provide the such information.

Comment: Could you please provide a examples? Also if this seems to be the answer you were looking for please mark it as an answer, thanks :)

Comment: Actually you answer is revealing the truth of communicate with urls, you are right we can't use WebClient, but some friends who are also beginner in xamarin are frequently using WebClient, and they don't have answer that why they are able to use WebClient while I am not. So I have vote up but I am not able to accept it as answer. Sorry for it.

Comment: Perhaps your friends are accessing WebClient in a platform specific library (e.g. iOS has an implementation of WebClient).